# How do I convince VS2012 it has update 5?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I have Visual Studio 2012 as my dev environment.
I installed Update #5 after its release several months ago.

However, I intermittently get informed by the VS updater that there's an update available.
Checking the notification, it's always Update 5. I've tried downloading it from the updater and running the update - I get prompted to repair or uninstall.

Repair does not help. I am trying uninstall/reinstall, but I do not expect it to work.

I'm concerned that this issue may prevent me from getting future updates.
How can I move past Update 5?

EDIT: I've uninstalled and installed it again. The issue persists.

Comment: There most likely won't be a future update for 2012. 2015u1 is the most recent update to 2012 if you think of it.

Comment: @jessehouwing Fair point. I guess I could just ignore this, but I was hoping to actually fix it.